# Array isn't getting overridden in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, array-filter

I'm creating a to-do list project. where I'm trying to delete a todo when the user clicks on the delete button. I'm using the array's filter method to remove that clicked todo. But when I refresh, that deleted todo comes back. the reason is that It's not getting removed from the local storage. There's something wrong with the event listener at the very bottom of the javascript file. I'm trying to overrides the array with whatever filter method returns and saving it to the local storage but still it doesn't work.

**Javascript file**

```
import Todo from './todo.js';
import './style.css';

const TODO_LIST_KEY = 'TODO_LIST_KEY';
const template = document.querySelector('#list-item-template');
const todoListContainer = document.querySelector('#list');
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const inputField = document.querySelector('#todo-input');

const loadList = () => {
  const dataInStringFormat = localStorage.getItem(TODO_LIST_KEY);
  return JSON.parse(dataInStringFormat) || [];
};

const renderTodo = (todo) => {
  console.log("I'm inside of renderTodo Method");
  const templateClone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
  const taskContent = templateClone.querySelector('[data-list-item-text]');
  taskContent.innerText = todo.description;
  const checkBox = templateClone.querySelector('[data-list-item-checkbox]');
  checkBox.checked = todo.completed;
  checkBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    todo.completed = checkBox.checked;
    saveList();
  });
  const listItem = templateClone.querySelector('.list-item');
  listItem.dataset.todoIndex = todo.index;
  todoListContainer.appendChild(templateClone);
};

let todoList = loadList();
todoList.forEach((todo) => renderTodo(todo));

const saveList = () => {
  localStorage.setItem(TODO_LIST_KEY, JSON.stringify(todoList));
};

const clearField = () => {
  inputField.value = '';
};

form.addEventListener('submit', () => {
  if (inputField.value === '') return;
  // Create a new Todo
  const todoTemplate = new Todo(todoList.length, inputField.value, false);
  todoList.push(todoTemplate); // new todo gets added to the list
  renderTodo(todoTemplate); //Here it adds that new todo to the list
  saveList();
  clearField();
});

todoListContainer.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches('[data-button-delete]')) return;

  // Get the todo that is clicked on
  const parent = e.target.closest('.list-item');
  const todoIndex = parent.dataset.todoIndex;
  // const todoItem = todoList.find((t) => t.index === todoIndex);
  parent.remove(); // removes from the screen
  todoList = todoList.filter((todo) => todo.index !== todoIndex);
  saveList();
});
```

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>To Do List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section class="todo-container">
      <ul class="todo-list" id="list">
        <li class="heading">
          <h3>Today's To Do</h3>
          <img
            src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/000000/refresh--v1.png"
            alt="refresh-icon"
            class="refresh-icon"
          />
        </li>
        <li>
          <form class="form">
            <label for="todo-input">
              <input
                type="text"
                id="todo-input"
                placeholder="Add to your list..."
              />
            </label>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <article class="footer">
        <a href="#">Clear all completed</a>
      </article>
    </section>

    <template id="list-item-template">
      <li class="list-item">
        <label class="list-item-label">
          <input type="checkbox" data-list-item-checkbox />
          <span data-list-item-text></span>
        </label>
        <img
          data-button-delete
          src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-glyphs/30/000000/trash--v1.png"
          alt="delete-icon"
          class="delete-icon"
        />
      </li>
    </template>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is `todo.index` a string or a number? `todoIndex` is a string, and you're using the strict `!==` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that `todo.index` is a number. `dataset` values are always strings, so `todo.index !== todoIndex` will always be true when `todo.index` and `todoIndex` are different types.

Set `todoIndex` to an integer:

```
const todoIndex = parseInt(parent.dataset.todoIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Barmar. It's working now. I could have spent a whole day and still won't be able to figure out this mistake.